# Allowing write access only to Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

How can we secure database via the rules that only allow Cloud Functions for Firebase to write data to certain locations, previously there was an option to add uid to admin client `databaseAuthVariableOverride` and use that uid in rules section, but now we initialise via `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` so I’m not to sure about how to add additional params in.

**EDIT**
is it a good idea to initiate with certificate for this instead? i.e

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("/path-to-cert"),
  databaseURL: "database-url",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: { uid: "some-id" }
});
```

What benefit does `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)` have over above and where is `functions.config()` actually getting data from, isn't this just a node module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally, at the top of your Cloud Functions code, you have:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

As part of the `firebase-functions` node module, you have access to a [`functions.config().firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.config.Config#firebase) which is just an object which has everything you need to initialize the Admin SDKs, including your Database URL and a credential implementation (based off of Application Default Credentials). If you `console.log(functions.config().firebase)` in your code, you will see it just is an object with these properties and a few other ones you may want to use in your code.

You can add [`databaseAuthVariableOverride`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.AppOptions#databaseAuthVariableOverride) to this object to [limit the Admin SDK's privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). You can just overwrite the object itself:

```
var firebaseConfig = functions.config().firebase;
firebaseConfig.databaseAuthVariableOverride = {
  uid: 'some-uid',
  foo: true,
  bar: false
};
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Or you can use something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the relevant details to a new object:

```
var firebaseConfig = Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, {
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: 'some-uid',
    foo: true,
    bar: false
  }
});
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: IIRC, the order of the arguments to `Object.assign()` are important. In the rare case that `functions.config().firebase` contains the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` property, it would override the one you've specified above. I'd recommend using `Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, { /* your overriding values */ })` to ensure that whatever you set stays as the final value.

Comment: Is it a good idea to initiate admin with custom service worker cert instead?

Comment: @Ilja - You can, but there is no benefit to doing that over using the credential provided in `functions.config().firebase`. And it requires you to manage your own service account key file, which is generally bad practice.

@samthecodingman - Thanks for the tip. I've updated my code sample.

Comment: It looks like the name of your project in firebase is the uid for your cloud functions. I'm still looking for documentation for further info.

Comment: I had a confusion with Cloud Functions and Firebase Functions, then I was trying to use this code within a Firebase Function. If any wants to know how to give only to a Firebase function to write access, the answer was written here http://stackoverflow.com/q/43642900/894026 taking care to indicate within the rules to deny to everybody